# How get real time voltage?

Tags: windows

Is there a way to retrieve the voltage being supplied to a computer in real time?

Comment: Different voltages are being applied to different components... I assume you're specifically asking about the "CPU core voltage"?

Comment: Yes, but I would also be interested in finding out as much about this subject as possible.  If you know of a reference that would be great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use WMI to get some of that information. I used the [WMI Code Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&displaylang=en) to come up with this VB script which returns the [Win32_Processor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394373(VS.85).aspx) CurrentVoltage value. If you have a laptop, there is also some battery information available in WMI.

```
strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2") 
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery( _
    "SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor",,48) 
For Each objItem in colItems 
    Wscript.Echo "-----------------------------------"
    Wscript.Echo "Win32_Processor instance"
    Wscript.Echo "-----------------------------------"
    Wscript.Echo "CurrentVoltage: " & objItem.CurrentVoltage
Next
```